# Where could I find a code example which adheres to both OOP principles and SOLID principles?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, design-patterns, solid-principles

Where could I find a c# code example which adheres to both OOP principles and SOLID principles?

I searched google but couldn't find any code example or a solution to a business problem which is directly related to address these 2 sets of principles.

Thanks

Comment: Things you mentioned usually don't occur at the same time. Lots of code examples are usually addressing one simple principal. If you search for something complete, you should follow an open source project.

Comment: Exactly, I've seen many examples which shows only 1 principle but not a whole package like one solution for a business problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend Mark Seemann's book : [Dependency Injection in .Net](http://www.manning.com/seemann/) which is amazing!
it has all the SOLIDity built in already and great detailed examples!

Comment: can you also include http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/encapsulation-solid which is also by Mark Seemann and the code for it is at  https://github.com/jpvantuyl/mark-iv-special-coffee-maker

Comment: I would second the plural sight course. Just finished it and it is eye opening.

Comment: @DLNarasimhan - I'm not sure if that is the exact code from the pluralsight course. Similar maybe, but not the same.

Answer (score 1):

There are many OOP *and* SOLID principles, having them all together in a single piece of code would be rather confusing.

I'd recommend you look at each princple in isolation, to really get a feel of what it is trying to achieve.

There are plenty of books which are crammed with code samples for you to look at. I like [Professional ASP.NET Design Patterns by Scott Millet](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Professional-ASP-NET-Design-Patterns-Millett/dp/0470292784). His code is here: http://aspnetdesignpatterns.codeplex.com/

This book also has a sample project (an e-commerce store) which combines a collection of the design patterns and principles. This will help you get a feel for how they fit together.

Comment: Well, thanks but I believe it should be possible having all the principles demonstrated in one project. I didn't mean all principles in 1 class of course.

Comment: It's entirely possible - the sample project I mentioned is very helpful as it covers the *rationale* for using each princple or pattern, which is arguably more useful than knowing what each pattern does.